# Resizing of label in xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I searched but didn't find any answer, this is my problem :

I display some labels with one char in a row for example F O O D is 4 label with one character.

I replace characters with another one when we click on it. But if i replace a I by a W for example, W appear cropped for like 0,2 seconds and then autoresize label to display it correctly. Is there a way to handle this ?

I don't know if the explanation is clear enough, if it is not i will try to explain it better.

Comment: yes, specify a fixed width large enough to accommodate both strings

Comment: I put the four `label` to the `Gird`, running result like this thread https://imgur.com/a/QQwgB3l,

Comment: ok thank you i will try with a grid. I didn't found fixed with to handle that.

Comment: Ok, waitting for your update.

Comment: Resolved by setting minimunWidthRequest on the label :)

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, please post your solution to answer and accept it, it will help others who have similar issue.